# jQuery ui drop (move) elements between tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, draggable, droppable

I want to realize moving elements between tabs using jquery ui. If I want drop element to another tab - droppable block (.elements) doesn't catch hover event (outline doesn't want to apply), but dropping works correctly.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$('.elements').children().draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    opacity: 0.9,
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 1000,
    cursorAt: { left: 50, top: 20 },
});

// drop into needle element
$('.elements').droppable({
    accept: '.element',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    activeClass: "can-drop",
    hoverClass: "drop-here",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('Drop');
    }
});

// drop
$('.ui-tabs-nav').children().droppable({
    accept: '.element',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    over: function( event, ui ) {        
       $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 1);
    }
})
```

You can see [my example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcAndry/h7raxjyu/).

Can someone help me? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you need something like **[this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637425/struggling-with-jquery-ui-sortable-and-tabs-would-like-to-move-items-around-tab)** and **[this demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zeTP8/)**

Comment: No, I don`t need drop element into tab button. I need  switch tab when cursor is over tab button and drop into new tab content (there can be two or more droppable areas).

Comment: I have already found answer for my question: draggable has function to reset offsets:

`$.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(ui.draggable.draggable('instance'));`

Work example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcAndry/h7raxjyu/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found answer for my question: draggable has function to reset offsets:

```
$.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(ui.draggable.draggable('instance'));
```

Worked example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcAndry/h7raxjyu/4/)